# IMAP config for Mail.app OSX - not showing folders properly

Tags: macos, mail.app, imap

I've configured my mail.app IMAP settings on OSX (Mountaion Lion 10.8.4) and it doesn't show account folder properly (it's empty). However, in Mailboxes section account is shown correctly, but all IMAP folders are actually one < Inbox > folder. I want to render IMAP folders separately.

I ve entered exactly the same configuration to my iPad and it is working correctly in iPad mail client

Comment: Is it possible the account folder is hidden (minimized)? Hover your cursor over the account name and a link should appear either reading "Hide" or "Show". If it says "Show", click on it, and the folder list should appear. Does this resolve the issue?

Comment: What`s the mail server? Something popular like Gmail, or is it a private one?